# lag function in R applied on grouped data frame producing only NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate the difference between the number of visits between semesters for a given client in a data frame but I am getting only NA when using the dplyr function lag, the code I am using is;

```
DF %>% group_by(IdCliente_F, Semestre) %>% 
       summarise(Numero_Visitas = n(),
                 Per_Change_Frequency = Numero_Visitas - dplyr::lag(Numero_Visitas))
```

The result I am getting is the following

```
# A tibble: 12,656 x 4
# Groups:   IdCliente_F [6,192]
   IdCliente_F Semestre   Numero_Visitas Per_Change_Frequency
         <dbl> <date>              <int>                <int>
 1           0 2019-07-01             22                   NA
 2      A      2019-01-01              1                   NA
 3      B      2019-07-01              1                   NA
 4      C      2019-01-01              9                   NA
 5      C      2021-01-01              3                   NA
 6      C      2021-07-01              1                   NA
 7      D      2021-07-01              1                   NA
 8      E      2019-07-01              3                   NA
 9      E      2020-01-01              1                   NA
10      E      2020-07-01              5                   NA
```

And I am expecting the following:

```
# A tibble: 12,656 x 4
# Groups:   IdCliente_F [6,192]
   IdCliente_F Semestre   Numero_Visitas Per_Change_Frequency
         <dbl> <date>              <int>                <int>
 1           0 2019-07-01             22                   NA
 2      A      2019-01-01              1                   NA
 3      B      2019-07-01              1                   NA
 4      C      2019-01-01              9                   NA
 5      C      2021-01-01              3                   -6
 6      C      2021-07-01              1                   -2
 7      D      2021-07-01              1                   NA
 8      E      2019-07-01              3                   NA
 9      E      2020-01-01              1                   -2
10      E      2020-07-01              5                    4
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Semestre` value is different within each `IdCliente_F`. You probably want to `group_by` only `IdCliente_F` and not `Semestre`.

Comment: By that data, no group has more than one row in it. While some of your groups have at least 2 rows in them (see that you have `6,192` groups and `12,565` rows), I think you may be over-grouping your data

Comment: I am trying to calculate the change in number of visits between each semester for each one of the clientes, thats why I am grouping by both IdCliente_F and Semestre

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate the difference between `Semestre` if you are only looking at one `Semestre` at a time. Try just `group_by(IdClient_F)`.

You can also reduce your calculation (no need for `lag`) to use just `diff`.

```r
DF %>%
  group_by(IdCliente_F) %>%
  mutate(Numero_Visitas = n(), Per_Change_Frequency = c(NA, diff(Numero_Visitas))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    IdCliente_F Semestre   Numero_Visitas Per_Change_Frequency
#    <chr>       <chr>               <int>                <int>
#  1 0           2019-07-01              1                   NA
#  2 A           2019-01-01              1                   NA
#  3 B           2019-07-01              1                   NA
#  4 C           2019-01-01              3                   NA
#  5 C           2021-01-01              3                    0
#  6 C           2021-07-01              3                    0
#  7 D           2021-07-01              1                   NA
#  8 E           2019-07-01              3                   NA
#  9 E           2020-01-01              3                    0
# 10 E           2020-07-01              3                    0
```

In this case, there are very few results to see since the sample data only has 1-3 observations per `IdCliente_F`, but the process should work for fuller data.

---

Data

```r
DF <- structure(list(IdCliente_F = c("0", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E"), Semestre = c("2019-07-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2019-07-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-07-01"), Numero_Visitas = c(22L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L), Per_Change_Frequency = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```